# Making a Manipulate showing a the motion of a particle

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d, physics

Solving a differential equation I got to the following result

```
-(((R[n*Pi - t/w] Cos[t/w])/(n*Pi))
```

Then, using this solution, I create .

```
circuloedisco[t_, w_, R_, n_] :=
 Show[
  Graphics[
    {Circle[{0, 0}, R], {Cyan, Thickness[0.005], 
     Line[{{0, 
        0}, {(( w*t)/(n*Pi) - 1) R*
         Sin[w*t], (( w*t)/(n*Pi) - 1) R*
         Cos[w*t]}}]},
    {Red, PointSize[0.05], 
     Point[{(( w*t)/(n*Pi) - 1) R*
        Sin[w*t], (( w*t)/(n*Pi) - 1) R*
        Cos[w*t]}]},

    {Yellow, PointSize[0.08], Point[{0, R}]},
    {Green, PointSize[0.08], Point[{0, -R}]}}, AspectRatio -> 1,
   Axes -> True],
  ParametricPlot[{(( w*T)/(n*Pi) - 1) R*
     Sin[w*T], ((w*T)/(n*Pi) - 1) R*
     Cos[w*T]}, {T, 0.001, t}]
  ]
```

After this I create a `Manipulate` to simulate, but I have two problems. When I change the values of `w` and `r`, nothing happens in the blue path of the phenomenon.

```
Manipulate[ 
  GraphicsRow[{circuloedisco[t, w, R, n]}], 
  {t, 0, (2*n* Pi)/w, 0.0001}, 
  {w, 2.05, 18.21}, 
  {{R, 5}, 2 , 10}, 
  {n, 1, 7, 1},
  ControlPlacement -> Top,
  SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

I would like to make this `Manipulate` in 3D. Anyone know how? 
And why do the controls for `w` and `r` change nothing?

Comment: I believe the only problem is the use of `pi` where you meant to write `Pi` -- capitalization matters.  With that one change I get an apparently working Manipulate: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6LQoi.png

Comment: Yeah, it works. I think in the copy/paste i had some troubles, but when you change some variables the simulation still the same, in theory should change the path.

Comment: The problem with your `r` variable is caused by the automatic scaling of the plot. If you look carefully you will see that when `r` is changed, the coordinate system ticks change value rather than the radius of the disk.

Comment: @dcvilela - How do you want to make this 3D?  Everything I see is 2D, what would the z dimension be?

Comment: @JasonB, something like this!

Comment: Clear[f, x, y, t, surfaceplot]
{x[t_], y[t_]} = (t/2) {Cos[t], Sin[t]};
f[x_, y_] = 2 E^(-x^2 - y^2);
surfaceplot2 = 
  Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, {y, 0, 6 Pi}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}];
parPlot = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t], f[x[t], y[t]]}, {t, 0, 6 Pi}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
Manipulate[
 Show[parPlot, 
  Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize -> 0.06, 
    Point[{x[tp], y[tp], 
      f[x[tp], y[tp]]}]}]], "Manipular partícula", {tp, 0, 6 Pi, 
  Pi/64}]

Answer (score 1):

When the plot range is fixed, your controls all seem to work. Try adding a plot range option to `circuloedisco` as follows:

```
circuloedisco[t_, w_, R_, n_] :=
  Show[
   Graphics[...],
   ParametricPlot[...],
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
```

Then

```
Manipulate[circuloedisco[t, w, R, n],
  {t, 0, (2*n*Pi)/w, 0.0001},
  {w, 2.05, 18.21},
  {{R, 5}, 2, 10},
  {n, 1, 7, 1},
  ControlPlacement -> Top,
  SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

will look like this

[image: demo]